# for loop cant find object value in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, for-loop

I have an array with cards as objects:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var totalPlayer = 12;    
var cards = [
            {"card": 2, "value": 2, "suit": "d"}, 
            {"card": 2, "value": 2, "suit": "c"}, 
            {"card": 2, "value": 2, "suit": "h"}, 
            {"card": 2, "value": 2, "suit": "s"}, 
            {"card": 3, "value": 3,...
            {"card": "a", "value": 11, "suit": "s"}];
$('#butStart').click(processIt);
```

And a loop:

```
function processIt() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        if (cards[i].card === "a" && totalPlayer > 11) {
            cards[i].value = 1;
        }
        else if (cards[i].card === "a") {
            cards[i].value = 11;
        }
    }
    alert(cards[50].value + cards[50].card);
}
```

I cant figure out why I'm getting the error message "can't read property 'card' of undefined"

Comment: Have you tried using `for (var i = 0; i < cards.length-1; i++)`?

Comment: have you just got a typo in your cards array for one of the objects

Comment: Yep, found it double ',', sorry, and thanks guys.

Comment: Could you check my answer please ? If it works for you, let's validate it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because your JSON doesn't have 51 items in it...?

Comment: If that was it, the error would be on `.value` instead of `.card`. And there isn't any JSON in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote all your data, I've tried with it and it worls like a charm :

```
var cards = [
            {"card": "2", "value": "2", "suit": "d"}, 
            {"card": "2", "value": "2", "suit": "c"}, 
            {"card": "2", "value": "2", "suit": "h"}, 
            {"card": "2", "value": "2", "suit": "s"}, 
            {"card": "3", "value": "3",...
            {"card": "a", "value": "11", "suit": "s"}];
```

Also, you need to pass the data to your function :

```
$('#butStart').click(processIt(cards));
function processIt(cards) {...}
```